# Open Map directions with WP7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, dictionary, navigation

I want to be able to get directions to an address I have hard coded into a button. I want to be able to touch the button that reads "Directions Here" and have it switch to the bing maps application on the phone and give me driving directions...

Q: how can I open another application from within my application? or how can I get the directions to my address from a user's current location to appear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bing Maps directions task. helping link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394024(v=vs.105).aspx

or you can use bing map Rest services. helping link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx